# Dynamic Dictionary c# - create with int as a key

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic

I am new to the topic of creating dynamic dictionaries in c#. Most of the examples there online are with Dictionary of `<string,object>`.
How can I create one with integer as a key (`Dictionary <int, object>`), after I want for example to parse .csv file into dynamic dictionary, with row number as the key?

This is my code:

```
public class DynamicDictionary<TValue> : DynamicObject, IEnumerable
{
    private Dictionary<int, TValue> _dictionary;
    public DynamicDictionary()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TValue>();        
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        TValue data;
        int rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(binder.Name);
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(rowNum, out data))
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("There is no key by that row number");
        }

        result = data;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        int rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(binder.Name);
        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(rowNum))
        {
            _dictionary[rowNum] = (TValue)value;
        }
        else
        {
            _dictionary.Add(rowNum, (TValue)value);
        }
        return true;
    }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

How can I set and get values from this dictionary?

Because this code is wrong:
myDict.1,myDict.2 etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side-note: why you provide a method `TryGetMember` that returns a `bool` and uses `dictionary.TryGetValue` to check if it contains a key, but you don't return `false` but throw a `KeyNotFoundException`? You should also use `int.TryParse(binder.Name)` and return `false` if that couldn't be converted to an `int`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That was really bugging me too ;) Likewise `TrySetMember()`, only without the exception.

Comment: @OP: It's not obvious from your question what is going wrong. Can you be more explicit? For example, state what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You are not getting any additional benefit over using `var d = new Dictionary<int, string>()` in your code sample. I think you're confusing generics with dynamic objects.

Comment: Why not just use a `DataTable`?  That has row numbers...  Or for that matter, just a `List` if there aren't any gaps in the integer sequence.

Comment: I will re-phrase my questions: What is the right way to use dynamic dictionary with integer as a key?